# Find a constant in two simultaneous equations with no solutions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am having trouble figuring out this question; could anyone explain it to me? Thanks a lot in advance!

The simultaneous equations do not have a solution. Find *k*.
$$2x-3ky=1$$
$$4x+(k+2)y=5$$

I am unable to find *x* or *y* as expected using substitution and cancellation, since there are no solutions. I do not know how to isolate *k* or find *k* in terms of *x* or in terms of *y*.

Comment: Well, I would "solve" the equations by multiplying the first equation by $-2$ and then adding the two equations together; then you can solve for $y$ in terms of $k$ only.

Answer (score 2):

$2x-3ky=1\iff 4x-6ky=2$.

Now do you see there is no solution if $-6k=k+2$?

Now can you find $k$?

Answer (score 1):

That system will have no solutions if and only if there is some number $\alpha\ne0$ such that$$4x+(k+2)y=\alpha(2x-3ky)$$and that $5\ne\alpha\times1=\alpha$. But$$4x+(k+2)y=\alpha(2x-3ky)\iff\alpha=2$$and, indeed, if $\alpha=2$, then $5\ne\alpha$. On the other hand\begin{align}4x+(k+2)y=2(2x-3ky)&\iff k+2=-6k\\&\iff k=-\frac27.\end{align}

Comment: did you mean $-\color{red}2/7$?

Comment: Sure. Thank you.